# Swift 4 + OpenCV - Detecting quadrilateral corners

Tags: c++, opencv, polygon, corner-detection

I am using OpenCV 3 and Swift 4 to build a simple application to detect the four corners of a quadrilateral contained in an acquired photo.

For example, I expect for the following [input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B3viq.png)
to have the following [output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lJoSO.png).

Does OpenCV provide a method to obtain this result?
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I think you're going to get further if you explain what you've already tried, in particular what you've already read up on using the OpenCV library.

Comment: see [squares.cpp](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/samples/cpp/squares.cpp)